# OCR / ICR for handwritting and logos

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have to do the following task on Python and I have not idea where
    to begin:

1. OCR of handwritten dates
2. Page/document orientation detection for pretreatment
3. Stamp and Logo Detection and classification

   a.  Orientation variation included 
    b.  Quality degradation to be considered 
    c.  Overlying Primary Content

Anybody could help me? 
THANKS IN ADVANCE¡¡

Comment: Your question is so general. Specify your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can `ocrmypdf` to extract text from a pdf. It will extract text from the page and return a pdf same like original pdf with text on it. For detection of logos, you need to implement a computer vision-based model. if you need more details then please specify your requirement in details